# Facebook application that allowed to post on friends wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

i created an app that supposed to be allowed to post on friends wall.

i get the error:

FAILED ((#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application - Type: OAuthException - Code: 200)

i read tens of posts and watched videos about this error and others.
i don't understand one thing: does my app can post on other friends wall or not?

i read about action types but didn't understand that one thing.

This is my app , it is live:

[image]

This is the status of my app:

[image]

and this is the "review status" :

[image]

do i get this error becuase i don't have action types?
do i need to add action type? or posting on others wall is a "common" action type that doesn't need to be speicfied?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting to friends' wall with Graph API via 'feed' connection failing since Feb 6th 2013](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-wall-with-graph-api-via-feed-connection-failing-since-feb)

Comment: Thanks guys , i read the previous posts before posting this one. i just thought that since this is a "new" change, maybe a way to do that was found by someone in the last couple of months. i thought it was worth the try ;) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone that stumbles across this question in the future, please note that Facebook disabled the ability to post to a friends' wall via the Graph API as of February 2013.

See their [Platform Update](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/02/06/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)s from the time this change went live: